# How To Read Sound Frequency using Mobile Microphone?

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am working on an application. Here I want to read various sounds using Android Application. I know how to record in Android. Now what I want to do is to read a sound and based on its frequency I want to display it on Android Screen. So how can I read the frequency in Hz or KHz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to perform a [discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) on your recorded audio samples. You can write code yourself or use a library for it. Unfortunately I have no idea which FFT libraries exist for Java, but I am sure you can google that. I found two in 2 minutes:

1. http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/FourierTransform.html
2. https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms