# How to detect Ultrasound waves using android device

Tags: android

I have ultrasound waves created by device and my android device should detect those ultrasound waves and fetch the information from the waves. The information like : frequency, user information etc..

How to program this in android?

Thanks & regards,
Tushar

Comment: Just write a function called ultraSoundDetection and add it to your code.  By the way, where is your code?

Comment: Please Visit my this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9044747/996493)

Comment: The code will be in Android device..so what this ultraSoundDetection function will do..Does it read any file and wave signals?

Answer (score 0):

You need custom hardware to record ultra wave sounds on an Android device. Normally, a microphone can only record frequencies up to about 20kHz, and depending on the device maybe not even that.

Comment: Nope. Microphones can (and have) registered well above 20khz for... well... ever. Phones included.Specs list the intended, not operational range; diaphragms _physically_ resonate to capture sound, so if it's optimum operation peaks at 20kHz, that means it will capture much higher but quality will degrade on a curve, not a shelf. If a recording cuts off at 20kHz, the _capturing device_ cut it off with a band pass gate. How high a mic captures past spec varies unit by unit.

Acoustical physics aside, [there's this.](https://www.wired.com/2016/11/block-ultrasonic-signals-didnt-know-tracking/)